# How to add multilines commit messages via command line - GIT?

Tags: bash, git, macos, shell

I create this alias on my Mac OS and my Linux, when I'm lazy to type in a commit message.

I ran   `PUSH`  it triggered

It will push to current branch with these sample commands

```
PUSH () {
    message=$(git diff --name-only)
    git commit -am "update $message"
    git push origin $(git rev-parse --abbrev-ref HEAD)
    git log --name-status HEAD^..HEAD
    git diff HEAD^ HEAD
}
```

> git diff --name-only

```
app/Http/Controllers/BabyController.php                                                                            
resources/views/layouts/be/baby/scripts.blade.php                                                                  
resources/views/layouts/be/baby/styles.blade.php
```

I would like to add a breakline \n to each line like this :

```
app/Http/Controllers/BabyController.php\n                                                                            
resources/views/layouts/be/baby/scripts.blade.php\n                                                                   
resources/views/layouts/be/baby/styles.blade.php\n
```

## How do I do that?

Comment: Commit messages provide the *why*. Why was this change made? This information is vital to understanding the code in the future. You're providing the *what*. What files were changed? This information is already available from `git log --name-only`. Your message might as well be "updated some stuff" for all the value it will be. Because only you know the why, I would recommend you do not automate your commit messages.

Comment: I would also recommend against pushing every commit. A commit is a single unit of change with an explanation for the change. A push shares those changes with the world. Before you share your work, there's a lot of revisions which can be done to your commits like rebasing and amending. See [Rewriting History](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Tools-Rewriting-History) for more. Once you share your work you're stuck with them (or, at least, it's harder).

Comment: I appreciate your suggestion, and I totally understand. I never do that at work or ina group project that someone but me will see the commit messages. Sometimes, it's beyond midnight, and it's for one of those moment that we just want to PUSH quick, and PULL quick so we can be done with it on our test personal project. :)

Comment: That is an edge case. Do you need a script for that edge case? If you do, the commit message still has no value. And you probably don't want to make it easy to push after midnight. Instead, consider `git commit -a -m wip` (Work In Progress) and go to sleep. Then in the morning finish up and `git commit --amend` with a proper commit message.

Comment: @cyber8200 - unsure if Iunderstood your question right. do you want to retain the existing new lines or add extra new lines. `git diff --name-only > message.txt` and then `git commit -aF message.txt` will do the former. However for me, your existing function already retains the spaces (I'm on Windows though - maybe that makes a difference)

Comment: @Schwern: _I would also recommend against pushing every commit._  Isn't pushing also a means for backing up your work? If your local hard disk crashes, everything since the last `push` is lost.

Comment: @user1934428 And you'll lose everything else on the drive. Git is not a backup service. Backup properly.

Answer (score 0):

If you want your commit messages to be multiline through command line you can do this:

```
git commit -m "first line" -m "second line" -m "third line"
```